# Two Django projects in different Django versions

Tags: python, django, session

I have Django project developed on Django 1.2, and I can't update it to newer version. I need add here an app, which developed on Django 1.4.

How can I start this as different projects on different versions and share user session in them?

How to setup correct url settings (ex. first must be `/`, second - `/app`)?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this blog post](http://dustinfarris.com/2012/2/sharing-django-users-and-sessions-across-projects/) on how to share users and sessions across two different projects. You will not require to *match the session cookie domain* since both your projects are already on the same domain.

**Note**: also read the comments, some important advice there in case you need help troubleshooting.

Re: URL settings - Obviously you cannot mount both projects on the same root. If project 1 is mounted on `/`, then you can mount the second project on `/app`. You can then configure project #2's URLs to use its root `/` (which is actually domain.com/app) directly for the new app's URLs. If you use `/somethingelse` for that app, your complete URL becomes `/app/somethingelse`.

Comment: You'll also need to make sure the Django 1.4 app is configured to use the old password hashing, because there's a new default in 1.4. Otherwise the user password field will automatically be updated upon first login in the 1.4 app, rendering it incompatible with the 1.2 app.